# Terminate a text search in less(1) and continue to read thru a Unix pipe

Tags: pipe, less

```
gunzip < 100terabytes.txt.gz | less
```

`less(1)` reads as many lines as necessary to fill your screen and then stops to `read(2)`.  As a result, `gunzip(1)` is blocked on `write(2)` as the pipe becomes full.

As you scroll down, `less(1)` issues `read(2)` again and again, and as the pipe is consumed, `gunzip(1)` is allowed to issue `write(2)`.  You have full flexibility in going back and forth here (assuming `gunzip < 100terabytes.txt.gz` doesn't complete.)

Everything is fine so far.

You can start a text search in `less(1)` with `/`.  But when the search string is not found in `100terabytes.txt`, `less(1)` essentially becomes unresponsive. You can terminate the search with `Ctrl-C`. **But** it seems to shut down the pipe between `gunzip(1)` and `less(1)`.  I don't like this.  I want to manually scroll down to consume more lines from `gunzip(1)` after I give up a text search.  It this possible?

I'm **not** asking for advice like `gunzip < 100terabytes.txt.gz | grep pattern | less`

### Update

You can experiment with `od -v /dev/zero | less`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, that's the whole shell *job* (process group) that receives the SIGINT, `less` intercepts it to abort the search, but `gunzip` will terminate. To avoid that, you could do:

```
(trap '' INT; gunzip < file.gz) | less
```

so that `gunzip` ignores the SIGINT,
but note that you won't be able to interrupt `gunzip` anymore after that.

For `gunzip`, that's probably fine, as all you need to do is quit `less` after which `gunzip` will die of a SIGPIPE the next time it writes something, but for applications that just hang without outputting something, that would be more of a problem (you'd still be able to use <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> for SIGTSTP or <kbd>Ctrl+\</kbd> for SIGQUIT though).

Also note that some commands like `pv` or `ping` install their own SIGINT handler which would revert our `trap '' INT`.

You can create a function to save typing like:

```
iless() {
  (trap '' INT; "$@") | less
}

iless gunzip < file.gz
```

Or:

```
noint() (trap '' INT; "$@")

noint gunzip < file.gz | less
```

But note that for:

```
gunzip < file.gz | grep foo | less
```

you'd need to write it:

```
noint gunzip < file.gz | notint grep foo | less
```

or:

```
noint eval 'gunzip < file.gz | grep foo' | less
```

or:

```
iless eval 'gunzip < file.gz | grep foo'
```

---

An alternative is to use process substitution:

```
less -f <(gunzip < file.gz | grep foo)
```

or (though not in `zsh`):

```
less < <(gunzip < file.gz | grep foo)
```

In those cases, the shell doesn't include the commands inside the process substitution in a the foreground process group (except in the second case for `zsh`). Their process group stays the same as the shell's. That means that they don't receive a SIGINT when you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Note that those processes won't be affected by <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+\</kbd> either.

Tested in `zsh`, `ksh93` and `bash`.

Comment: Ah, that explains why... Probably I end up in hitting `Ctrl-Z` followed by `killall -INT less` and `fg` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer but it may solve your problem. From `man less`:

```
       ESC-F  Like  F,  but  as soon as a line is found which matches the last
              search pattern, the terminal bell is rung and forward  scrolling
              stops.
```

This can be interrupted by `^C` but I don't know if it will break the pipe, because I couldn't reproduce your problem (I think one needs a very big input file to test this). I think it will not break the pipe, because usually you can repeatedly do `F` then `^C` on a growing file, and `F` still works (you still see the file growing).

The problem is: how to enter the "last search pattern" without freezing `less` if the pattern is not found? Maybe the `^K` option to `/` will help:

```
          ^K     Highlight any text which matches the pattern on the  cur-
                 rent screen, but don't move to the first match (KEEP cur-
                 rent position).
```

Edit: or, more simply, use `?` to "set" this "last search pattern".

Comment: I'm testing your suggestions with `less 481-2.1` on Debian.  `ESC-F` is not really useful;  I can skip as many matches as possible.  `/^K` freezes infinitely searching for the first match and `Ctrl-C` closes the pipe. It's just the same as plain `/`.  You can experiment with `od -v /dev/zero | less`.